# getting empty array from Angular http.post service

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

My '/messages' API is used to query mongodb for document with given 'hostname' and 'day'. When I test it with 'postman' I got correct response, array of objects. But when angular client used, it gives me empty array [], why?

**Controller**

```
apiSvc.post('/messages', {hostname: "XYZ", day: '1'})
            .then(function (response) {             
                console.log(response.data);
            });
```

**SERVICE**

```
.factory("apiSvc", function($http) {
        return {
            post: function(url,data) {
                return $http.post(url,data);                                  
            },            
        }
    })
```

**ROUTER**

```
router.post('/messages', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.hostname, req.body.day);
    Message.find({day: req.body.day, hostname: req.body.hostname},
        function(err, message) {                          
            res.send(message);
    });

});
```

Comment: Looking on server side I have this: 'VAL-VSX-02 1 string string
[]' for Angular service and this  for Postman: 'WAL-VSX-02 1 string string [{..}]' which is array of objects. So same request, different response..

Comment: Once again, looking at array length:  
VAL-VSX-02 1 string string
0  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Angular service
WAL-VSX-02 1 string string
42 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Postman